# calculating motion from angles

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

First, my apologies.  This question may have been asked many times before but I do not know the correct terms to search on..... and my school trigonometry is many years ago.  Pointing me to an appropriate already-answered question would be an ideal solution for me.

I am writing a program to do 3D view from an observer.  I want to calculate motion based upon the direction the observer is looking.  I currently define this as angle from directly ahead in two planes.  Rotation about the x (left-right) axis gives me elevation (elevationRadians), and rotation about y (up-down) axis gives me left-right.  Rotation about z never happens.

I need to calculate the change in cartesian coordinates caused by moving D units in the direction of view.

```
dx = D * cos(elevationRadians)
dy = D * sin(deflectionRadians)
```

But I now get two components for dz

```
dz = D * cos(deflectionRadians)
dz = D * sin(elevationRadians)
```

How should I combine these terms to give realistic movement?  Should I add them, average them, or something else?  Part of me thinks that simply adding them will give too large a dz. Could someone confirm, deny, or point me to a good resource for this please.......

Edit: rotation about y gives 'deflection..

My axes: x: left -> right, y: down -> up, z: behind -> in front.

Thanks to Andei's amswer which almost worked (I think our axes differed), I wound up with this:

dx = D cos(elevationRadians) cos(deflectionRadians)
dy = D sin(elevationRadians) sin(deflectionRadians)
dz =  D sin(elevationRadians)

which *seems* to work a lot better than what I had.

What is the mathematical term for what I am trying to do?  I need to read some theory preferably at the simple end of the scale.

Comment: look up "change to spherical coordinates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't define your axes correctly. You have rotation around $z$, and in the next sentence you say it never happens.

I think you should use polar coordinates. If you call $\theta$ the angle from the vertical direction $z$, $\theta=\pi/2-\text{elevationRadians}$, and $\phi=\text{deflectionRadians}$ is the angle that the projection in the horizontal plane makes with the $x$ axis, you have:$$\begin{align}x&=D\sin\theta\cos\phi\\y&=D\sin\theta\sin\phi\\z&=D\cos\theta\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahhh thank you.  I will give that a try.  I corrected my answer - rotation about *Y* gives deflection.

Comment: Note that my vertical axis is $z$

Comment: It may be that I am using different axes than you, but your solution did not work as given.  (Or it may be my inability to visualise these 3D spaces in code). I am having difficulty formatting the comments so I will edit my answer.

Comment: The one with elevation only is the vertical axis: dy=D sin(elevationRadians). Then if you have deflectionRadians measured from the x axis, you get dx=D cos(elevationRadians) cos(deflectionRadians), and dz= cos(elevationRadians) sin(deflectionRadians)

Comment: I was encountering two problems.  The coordinate system in the program I am using was different to the standard/mathematical one. I had to mentally transpose y and z.  Also the zero-points of each angle (elevation, azimuth) were not lined up in the same way.  Once I had made these transformations in my code it worked a treat. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I would look to solve this using utility methods contained in 3D Vectors. I'm not sure what you're using for creating the application, but I've found Unity 3D's documentation on 3D vector Math to be very easy to follow (regardless of whether you're working in Unity).

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/vector-maths

For example - in response to your specific question about the size of "dz" I would use the "normalize" method of a Vector3 which gives you a vector unit length of 1 and then scale this vector by whatever magnitude you need.

Comment: I am using javafx.  I had a quick look at the Unity documentation, and It seems to deal with vectors.  I had started to define the direction that I was looking in in terms of angles, and have dificulty converting these angles to vectors.  Perhaps I should define the direction in vector terms, and all the trigonometry would disappear.

Comment: I find that it's easier to think about and work with Vectors when handling motion or interaction in 3D. It's relative simply to go back and forth, but angles can be tricky in 3D (particularly when interpolating - see ["Gimbal lock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)). [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) offer a solution to this issue. You may not need this level of complexity, but it's probably not worth trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Unfortunately my imterface or the 'camera' requires angles, but the rest of the 3D model requires cartesian coordinates.  So I need to convert the camera angle to a vector(?).

Comment: I believe those angles are usually specified as Euler Angles. The Unity docs on [Rotation and Orientation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html) do a nice job of explaining the relationship.